# collinear and coplanar points on sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

let us consider following project from calculus book :

[image]

now  my afford and several notes to  first part, according to that link

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110518062027AAPmUyF

points are coplanar  if  determinant created in this link is zero,so let us take  example in  our project and check by matrix

```
A=[1 -1 2 1;2 -1 4 1;-1 -1 -1 1;1 4 1 1]

A =

     1    -1     2     1
     2    -1     4     1
    -1    -1    -1     1
     1     4     1     1
```

then determinant of this matrix is  det(A)

ans =

```
 5
```

which means that they are coplanar,also for answering question to collinearity,we should check following link

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html

clearly what  non coplanar fact means is that they are independent from each other,that why they are  non collinearity,is it right that assumption?what about gaussian elimination?what should be  coefficient matrix in this case?these points seperately denote  denote  $x$,$y$ and $z$ right?in this case we simple would have  for example for first point

$1+1+4+u-v+2*w=k$

$4+1+16+2*u-v+4*w=k$

$1+1+1-u-v-w=k$

$1+16+1+u+4*v+w=k$

or we get

$6+u-v+2*w=21+2*u-v+4*w=3-u-v-w=18+u+4*v+w$

where to use gaussian elimination?please help me,even if i will leave

$1+1+4+u-v+2*w=k$

$4+1+16+2*u-v+4*w=k$

$1+1+1-u-v-w=k$

$1+16+1+u+4*v+w=k$

these equations, ,then we would have

$6+u-v+2*w=k$

$21+2*u-v+4*w=k$

$3-u-v-w=k$

$18+u+4*v+w=k$

then clearly we have coefficient matrix,and should we apply  gaussian method there?because $k$ is unknow,for different  $k$,we would have different answers right?

Comment: if fourn points be coplaner can they lie on a sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to decide collinearity/coplanarity of *vectors* than of points. A set of $n$ points $P_1,\dots,P_n$ is collinear/coplanar if and only if the vectors $P_2-P_1,P_3-P_1,\dots, P_n-P_1$ and collinear/coplanar. One advantage is already seen: we have $n-1$ vectors to deal with.

The dimension of the linear span of a system of vectors is the *rank* of the matrix composed of those vectors. If the rank is $1$, the vectors are collinear. If it is $2$, they are coplanar but not collinear. If it is $3$, they are not coplanar. Note that *one* computation of matrix rank answers both collinearity and coplanarity questions at once.

For example, if given points are

$$(-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 2), (2, -1, 4), (1, 4 ,1)$$

we can consider the vectors

$$\langle 2,0,3\rangle, \langle 3,0,5\rangle, \langle2,5,2\rangle$$

formed as above. Put them into a matrix, either as rows or as columns:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2&0&3 \\ 3&0&5\\ 2&5&2\end{pmatrix}$$

The rank is $3$, thus the vectors are not coplanar, and neither are the points.

No $4\times 4$ determinants (as in Yahoo! Answer) are needed.

---

**Note** that my answer addresses your question about determining the collinearity of coplanarity of points. It does not address the problem in your book; in fact I don't even see what your question has to do with the problem in the book.

Comment: thanks for this,but what about part (a)  related to gaussian?how should i apply gaussian?please help me to actual problems

Comment: i need help please to basic part,about colinearity i have understood